# How can I add the second item in the linked list without overwriting the first one?

Tags: python, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I've implemented a linked list in Python. The first item gets inserted properly. But the second one overwrites it in the head node. And after that it works just fine.

```
class Node:
def __init__(self):
    self.data = None
    self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node()
        self.iterator = self.head

    def isEmpty(self):
        if self.head.data is None:
            return True

    def insert(self, value):
        if self.isEmpty():
            self.head.data = value

        else:
            while self.iterator.next is not None:
                self.iterator = self.iterator.next
            self.iterator.next = Node()
            self.iterator.data = value
            self.iterator = self.head

    def __str__(self):
        l = []
        while self.iterator.next is not None:
            l.append(self.iterator.data)
            self.iterator = self.iterator.next
        self.iterator = self.head
        return str(l)


t = LinkedList()
t.insert(2)
t.insert(4)
t.insert(8)
t.insert(6)
t.insert(10)
t.insert(12)
print(t)
```

Also in the **str** method how can I print the data if Head is the only node. (As Next of Head is None it will not enter the while loop.)

Comment: You really shouldn't use `self.iterator`. Use a local variable instead. Check it the node is `None` to decide whether to insert it. Not whether its `next` is `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you seem to overrwrite the data at self.iterator. Rather, you should set the data to the new node you created:

```
self.iterator.data = value
```

Fixed code:

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node()
        self.iterator = self.head

    def isEmpty(self):
        if self.head.data is None:
            return True

    def insert(self, value):
        if self.isEmpty():
            self.head.data = value

        else:
            while self.iterator.next is not None:
                self.iterator = self.iterator.next
            new_node = Node()
            new_node.data = value
            self.iterator.next = new_node
            self.iterator = self.head
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding self.iterator.next = Node() inside the if statement of the method insert solved it for me:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node()
        self.iterator = self.head

    def isEmpty(self):
        if self.head.data is None:
            return True

    def insert(self, value):
        if self.isEmpty():
            self.head.data = value
            self.iterator.next = Node()

        else:
            while self.iterator.next is not None:
                self.iterator = self.iterator.next
            self.iterator.next = Node()
            self.iterator.data = value
            self.iterator = self.head

    def __str__(self):
        l = []
        while self.iterator.next is not None:
            l.append(self.iterator.data)
            self.iterator = self.iterator.next
        self.iterator = self.head
        return str(l)
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 8, 6, 10, 12]
```